# Migrate dokuwiki to SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-online

We have a dokuwiki site that I want to migrate to SharePoint. I know I can go through and copy and paste, but I have hundreds of pages to copy over.

Answer (score 3):

The [Dokuwiki forums](http://forum.dokuwiki.org/thread/4954) suggest there is a way.  They also give [export](http://www.dokuwiki.org/export) options.  Those will at least let you get the data out.  I haven't seen any references to being able to import that though.

I will say this, the SharePoint wikis are nothing like Dokuwiki, Confluence, Mediawiki, etc.  The features are very dumbed down compared to those products.  Users may or may not like this.  If the users are entrenched into your Dokuwiki installation, I would reconsider migrating it all.

Comment: I dont agree. Dokuwiki is time consuming when compared to Sharepoint. Dokuwiki is like trying to create text documents you have very limited functionality compared to Sharepoint. When using Sharepoint its like editing an email or creating a word document. I just cant see the how you can compare the two.

Comment: The only thing wiki-like in SharePoint is the ability to link and create pages with the double bracket syntax [[]].  There is nothing wiki-like about it.  No meta discussion, no concurrent editing. It is by far anything of an enterprise level wiki.  I'd be more inclined to use Office Web Apps Word document library to serve as a wiki over a wiki.

Comment: Sounds like you're both talking about it from different perspectives: It may not be very wiki-ish, but if all they need is easy formatting and document linking, then the SharePoint wiki may well be what they want.