# How do I migrate a wiki to SharePoint Enterprise Wiki?

Tags: migration, wiki, enterprise-wiki

My company has a SharePoint installation where we are consolidating all of our technical IT documentation. Aside from the normal folders of documents which we'll manage in SharePoint, we also have a wiki on a no-longer supported platform (Perspective) that we want to migrate to SharePoint Enterprise Wiki. We can export from our existing Perspective wiki into DocuWiki format.

Once I've exported the DocuWiki formatted site into XML files, what are the steps to import those files into an Enterprise Wiki in SharePoint?

SharePoint Enterprise Wiki has been selected corporately as the wiki platform so please don't recommend other wiki solutions, this is what we're mandated to use.

I've also looked at [this question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/24545/migrate-dokuwiki-to-sharepoint) but it doesn't answer how to get the exported files *into* SharePoint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to write a custom import tool with the Client Object Model. If your export is well formatted in XML, it should not be very difficult. You need to import the HTML content of each page into a new Enterprise Wiki page in SharePoint.

That's the short version... In practice, there are a number of things you might want to tweak: parse and replace embedded links, crosslinks, image links, etc., create site columns that match your old wiki metadata (if any), prepare page layouts.

The technical aspects are fairly straightforward. The business implementation that will result in something your users are happy with, is not.